# Unexpected result from printf

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("He %c llo",65);
}
```

Output:  He `A` llo

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("He %c llo",13);
}
```

Output: `llo`. It doesnt print He.

I can understand that 65 is ascii value for A and hence `A` is printed in first case but why `llo` in second case.

Thanks

Comment: Those two examples appear to be completely identical.

Comment: edited. the argument in second is 13.

Comment: Is the output of the first really just `A` or is it `He A llo` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASCII 13 is carriage return, which on some systems simply moves the cursor to the beginning of the line you were just on.

Further characters then wipe out the earlier text.

Answer (score 5):

Man ascii:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
015   13    0D    CR  '\r'
```

Character `13` is carriage return so it prints `He` then returns to the beginning of the line and prints the remining `llo`.

Comment: Note: it returns to the beginning of current line not to the beginning of next line, to return to the beginning of next line you would use `\r\n` - carriage return, line feed.

Comment: stefanB: Or just `\n` in the case of *NIX and OS X, or plain `\r` in MacOS before OS X.

Answer (score 3):

It's just being rendered strangely due to the nature of a carriage return*.  You can see the characters that are output, by piping to another tool such as `xxd`:

```
$ gcc b.c && ./a.out | xxd
0000000: 4865 200d 206c 6c6f                      He . llo
$ gcc c.c && ./a.out | xxd
0000000: 4865 2041 206c 6c6f                      He A llo
```

* See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computer_analogues):

> On printers, teletypes, and computer terminals that were not capable of displaying graphics, the carriage return was used without moving to the next line to allow characters to be placed on top of existing characters to produce character graphics, underlines, and crossed out text.